# css postioning issue

Tags: css

What I am trying to do is, putting two divs in one line, the left div's width is fixed and the right one, gets resized when the browser is resized (achieved already). What I want to achieve is, set a resize limit for the right div, that is, the right div width decreases until the width is greater or equal to n px. after that the browser horizontal scroll.

(The reason for this is I have got a jquery tab on the right div with like 5 tabs, when I resize the browser the tabs jumps off on button of each other, hence I want to stop the right div to shrink until the last tab).

here is my code so far:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 300px; margin-right: 10px; ">

</div>

<div style="overflow: hidden;">

</div>
```

Please let me know if there is a better way of putting two div in one line (left width fixed and right resizable with limit).

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either be looking at min-width/max-width, or @media

For min-width just give a class or id to div2 and set min-width

```
    #div2{
       min-width:900px;
    }
```

For control on different screen sizes use @media and set max/min widths.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 499px) {
      /* rules that only apply for canvases narrower than 500px */
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
      /* rules that only apply for canvases wider than 500px */
    }
```

There's more information here: https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class='left'></div>

<div class='right'></div>

<styles>
.left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
.right {
    float: left;
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
</styles>
```